# TOP showing Multi Process with same name

Tags: htop

I'm trying to figure out why in top (CentOS) There are several programs that have a lot of processes with same name , instead one single instance.
I tried to understand this clearly, I hope someone here will help with good explaination.
from Programs that i encountered with many processes with top: 
nscd , php-fpm , httpd , nginx.

Thank you ,

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

this is because multiple instances of the same binary/process are running in parallel. for the mentioned server programs this most certainly is on purpose. it might be reconfigured per service, but then you lose all the advantages it brings, e.g. faster response times by concurrent handling of requests...